# Not logical operator

Tags: swift, uikit, logical-operators

I need help to understand the following codes.
Why does it print "yes" even if !test is equal to true.
Thanks

```
var test: Bool = false

if !test  {
    print("yes")
}

if !test == true  {
    print("oky")
}

print(!test)


Console:

yes
oky
true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- "test" variable is defined with default value 'false'.
- "if !test" is equal to "if !test == true", in both case your test is negated that means 'false' become 'true' and that's why your prints are executed.

I want to add that there are developers for whom the negative logic is hard to read. Below are some examples of such logical expressions.

**examples of logic that takes time to process::**

- view.isHidden = !isLoading
- view.isHidden = !hasData
- view.isHidden = !canAdd
- view.idHidden = !(data?.isEmpty ?? true)
- view.isHidden = !hasChanges

**possible solutions are:**

- create ‘isVisible’ on view
- use if-else

There is a great article that threats the subject in-depth:

[Don’t ever not avoid negative logic](https://schneide.blog/2014/08/03/dont-ever-not-avoid-negative-logic/)

> If you want to be nice to people with a challenged relationship with
> boolean logic, try to avoid negative formulations and negations.

Answer (score 0):

test equals false, as defined in your first line.

The not operator (!) returns true if the statement is false, and false if the statement is true.

Since test equals false, !test equals true.

The two conditions if (!test) and if (!test == true) are both met since !test is true, so the text is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Because if the condition after `if` is true, the commands get executed.

These lines are equivalent:

```
if !test  {

if !test == true  {
```

I think you might be confusing the value of `test` with the value of `!test`. The Not operator negates the value of whatever it acts upon, in this case the variable `test`.